# How to make bluetooth headset play beeps and vibrate?

Tags: java

When there is a incoming call,the bluetooth headset play beeps and vibrate. but now  i want my android app do these when there is no incoming call .by sending at command through rfcomm? but i don't know which command can be done. please tell me the way,thank you!